# How to create module for dagger 2

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I have read many articles about dagger 2 but I cant understand how to create module for dagger 2
Lets say i have three class A,B,C 
A is dependent on B and C
How do i create module and component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        ApplicationModule.class
})
public interface ApplicationComponent {

    void inject(@NonNull A a);
}
```

Module:

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {
    @NonNull
    private final Application application;

    public ApplicationModule(@NonNull Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @NonNull
    @Singleton
    Application provideApp() {
        return application;
    }

    @Provides
    @NonNull
    @Singleton
    B provideB() {
        return new B();
    }

    @Provides
    @NonNull
    @Singleton
    C provideC() {
        return new C();
    }
}
```

Your application class, where you init your component with module:

```
public class App extends Application {
    private ApplicationComponent applicationComponent;

    @NonNull
    public static App get(@NonNull Context context) {
        return (App) context.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        applicationComponent = prepareApplicationComponent().build();
    }

    @NonNull
    protected DaggerApplicationComponent.Builder prepareApplicationComponent() {
        return DaggerApplicationComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this));
    }

    @NonNull
    public ApplicationComponent applicationComponent() {
        return applicationComponent;
    }
}
```

Your A class (for example it's activity):

```
public class A extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Inject
    B b;
    @Inject
    C c;

    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        injectDependencies()
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // working with b and c
    }

    private void injectDependencies() {
        App.get(this).applicationComponent().inject(this);
    }
}
```